# Unexpected token ILLEGAL error importing css script in reactjs es6 file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using php to post data to node.js to render reactjs components server side.

The debug console shows that error `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` occurs when variable `component` returns `undefined`.

```
React = require('react'),
ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server'),
require('babel-core/register');
app.post('/something', function (req, res) {
    try {
        var view = './src/ItemPage';
        var component = require(view); <<<====== Error
        var props = req.body || null;
        res.status(200).send(
            ReactDOM.renderToString(
                React.createElement(component, props)
            )
        );
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});
```

The problem is due to importing the css script from grommet UI library in order to include css in the `bundle.js`. If I remove that style import line, the script is running okay. Why does the following class returns undefined in node? Is there a syntax error? It is compiled fine in webpack.

ItemPage Class:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tabs from 'grommet/components/Tabs';
import Tab from 'grommet/components/Tab';
import 'grommet/grommet.min.css'; <<=== Error !!!!

export default class ItemPage extends React.Component {

    render(){ return <Tabs>
        <Tab title="First Title">
            <h3>First Tab</h3>
            <p>Contents of the first tab !</p>
        </Tab>
        <Tab title="Second Title">
            <h3>Second Tab</h3>
            <p>Contents of the second tab</p>
        </Tab>
        <Tab title="Third Title">
            <h3>Third Tab!</h3>
            <p>Contents of the third tab</p>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    }
}


module.exports = ItemPage;
```

Comment: Node.JS can't require css-files. When u use webpack, it handle require('style.css') with https://github.com/webpack/css-loader

You do not use webpack on the server, perhaps?
One of the possible solutions: build bundle using webpack and run it on the server.

Comment: How are you building your app? Using webpack?

Comment: @Yozi, is it good to bundle css with js or should I just include the minify css in the html document?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr, yes I'm using webpack. I now understand that it is due to Node.js not able to require css files.

Comment: @RedGiant, yes, it good. because of this you can do awesome things like https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#local-scope

Comment: @RedGiant, It is also semantically. You can include a small css directly to the module, for example, `import './Header.css'` in Header.js
Webpack merge everything into one file for u.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to modularize your stylesheets with your other modules you should use a `css-laoder` with webpack.

Install it:

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

And configure it:

```
{
// ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
        ]
   }
}
```

That will make possible to require css.

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) and [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html).